# There's a bug with locking and removing post notices

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools, locked-questions, post-notices

There was [a question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154155/should-you-keep-a-copy-of-all-the-code-you-write) that had an "insufficient explanation" post notice, but it needed to be historical locked. If you lock a question with a lock (in my case, I used a historical lock) and then remove the post notice, you end with up no notice that the question is locked. And given [a comment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/structured-tag-cleanup-initiative-phase-ii/7296?noredirect=1#comment22451_7296), it appears that the answers weren't locked.

Removing post notices should not do anything with respect to closed or locked questions. It should only remove the notice (citation needed / current event / insufficient explanation).

Answer (score 5):

Locking questions without a post notice is supported, but not intended for regular use; its primary purpose is to prevent tampering with posts being handled by the system (spam, offensive, or migrated).

**Moderator locks always come with a post notice.** Indeed, the post notice is all that differentiates different "types" of locks; there is no separate "lock type" associated with the post.

You should generally not remove post notices after applying a lock. If you need to remove notices, do so *before* locking the post; if you forget, unlock it and clean it up before re-applying the lock.

Comment: The system allows me to do it, though. And what happens effectively undoes the lock. It may be "by-design", but maybe some kind of warning to be like "hey, you're about to undo stuff that you just did" would be nice. It's not intuitive or documented in the screens.

Comment: To elaborate: I intended to historically lock the question. The end result was a question that wasn't historically locked. If the issue was't pointed out to me quickly, I would never have noticed and we would have been confused down the road when we tried to figure out what happened.

Comment: Removing the option to remove notices on locked posts would probably be the safest way to avoid this; I can't think of a particularly good reason to use that option off-hand.

Comment: Could we remove the status-bydesign from this question and make it a feature-request to prevent removal of notices on locked posts? It's a little clunky, but I'd rather have a clunky mod tool than weirdness visible to users.

Comment: There are also older locks from the time when there were no reasons one could choose from to lock a post; there was just one "lock" button, which simply locked the post and added no notice.

Comment: Fwiw, I did remove that option for locked posts at some point @thomas