# Let's get these tags [locked] down - do we need them all?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just wrote a question about post notices on locked questions. When using the tag picker, I realized that we have three tags that are all really versions of the same tag:

- [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) - 86
- [locked-questions](/questions/tagged/locked-questions) - 152
- [locked-answers](/questions/tagged/locked-answers) - 8

The first of these is ambiguous. While most of the questions are about locks on posts, there are a few questions about vote locks, which has its own tag ([locked-votes](/questions/tagged/locked-votes)). These errant questions should be retagged leaving only post-related tags.

The second has the most uses but it is also too specific. Many of the questions here aren't *only* about locked questions. Many of them are about both question and answer locks (for example: [Allow moderators to fine-tune the effects of a lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321241/allow-moderators-to-fine-tune-the-effects-of-a-lock)).

The third has few questions and, like the questions version, they aren't necessarily specific *only* to answers.

So, my suggestion

1. Review all of the existing questions to be certain they're tagged correctly (particularly in the [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) group).
2. Merge and synonymize all three into a new tag - [locked-posts](/questions/tagged/locked-posts). This will hopefully prevent it from being used for non-post-related questions.

If [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) seems too ambiguous to synonymize, we could just merge that one without the synonym.

Comment: I agree with your proposal. The only possible difference between locked questions and answers is that historical locks (at questions) apply to answers too, AFAIK. But there is [tag:historical-lock] for this usecase. So let's do it.